# How to store query result to a generic list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The code below does not compile. The compiler error is

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnimeVoter.Models.MyTitleObject>' d:\dev\mvc\AnimeVoter\AnimeVoter\Controllers\SearchController.cs
```

Below is the code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
{
    string filter = collection["search_fld"];

    List<MyTitleObject> list = 
        (
        from O in db.Titles 
        join K in db.TitleDescriptions on O.Id equals K.TitleId
        where O.Name.ToLower() == filter.ToLower()
        select new { Name = O.Name, Description = K.Description, UrlImage = O.UrlImage, Votes = O.Votes }
        ).ToList(); // this is where the error points at

    return View(list);
}
```

where MyTitleObject is defined as

```
public class MyTitleObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UrlImage { get; set; }
    public int Votes { get; set; }
}
```

In summary what I am trying to achieve is to send the resulting list to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the type on the select line:

```
select new MyTitleObject { Name = O.Name, Description = K.Description, UrlImage = O.UrlImage, Votes = O.Votes }
```